Quart is unable to pass request object to CloudAdapter() in microsoft bot builder
I am trying to call an async function that accepts a request of type aiohttp.web.request, this is being called in one of my views using quart as the framework, the requests come as co-routines that cannot be passed and parsed like aiohttp.web.request. Can you please suggest how to achieve this???
adapter = CloudAdapter()
bot = convBot(configs)

@app.route("/message")
async def process_message(req: Request) -> Response:
    res = await adapter.process(req, bot)
    return res

In the adapter.process() function we access request.json attribute that seems to work when an object of aiohttp is passed and returns an error request.data was never awaited.
link to cloudAdapter class-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/cloudadapter?view=botbuilder-ts-latest
I am integrating my backend on quart with Azure bot service that connects to MS teams and redirects all messages to an endpoint, I am using Python botBuilder SDK, and trying to route the request received to the adapter.process function that is implemented as in the link.
